# Firebase DatabaseReference allows read data but not allows insert data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm programming an App in Android with firebase. In this class, the method `getTimestampFromServer()` works fine. In `onDataChange` event of the listener, it calls the method `updateCertificadoKey()`. This method inserts a value in the database reference, but nothing happens. The listener does not work.

I tried with `addOnCompleteListener()`, `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, `addValueEventListener()` but nothing happens. This reference allows read data from database, but not allows insert or update data.

I've revised the url and is ok. The database don't have restrictions (read=true, write=true).

This is my gradle configuration

```
compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.8.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
apt 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //para firebase client
```

This is the fragment of code:

```
private void getTimestampFromServer(){
    DatabaseReference refOffset = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(remoteConfig.getUrlTimeOffset());
    refOffset.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String aux = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            long offset = Long.parseLong(aux);
            long timestamp = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + offset;
            updateCertificadoKey(timestamp);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            showError(activity.getString(R.string.certificado_err_consec) + "\n" +
                    databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private void updateCertificadoKey(final long timestamp){
    String key = String.valueOf(timestamp);
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String url = remoteConfig.getRamaCertificados() + "/" + key;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(url);

    ref.child("test_child").setValue("test_value").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                String x = "INSERT OK!";
                Log.e("FLAG", x);
            }else{
                String x = task.getException().getMessage();
                Log.e("ERROR", x);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not very efficient for debugging your code. Did you already step through the code in a debugger? Does your `onDataChange()` get called? If yes, do you get to the `setValue()`? If yes, do you get into the `onComplete()`? If yes, what is the value of `task.isSuccessful()`? Knowing the answer to all of these will make it more likely someone here can help.

Comment: Yes sir, all the other options are querys and works fine, this is the first option to write data to database. This class was debugged and does not insert data. The method  getTimestampFromServer() works fine, but the method updateCertificadoKey(final long timestamp) does not work. I made a query and works fine, but not the insert, i have tested with several listeners, but in the debug the listeners was not executed. I'm using androidstudio 2.3. I used nodejs and postman and it works, the problem is only in android. The methods relatied by you are not executed.

Comment: Another thing: the class is not an activity, but receives the applicationContext for another methods, it affects?

Comment: So you you put a breakpoint on `ref.child("test_child").setValue("test_value")`, you get there?

Comment: Yes, i putted a breakpoint in this sentence and in the two parts of the internal condition (if task.isSuccessful()...), but apparently the sentence ref.child("test_child").setValue("test_value") is ignored, the debug does  not execute the condition and the control  returns to the caller method in the class

Comment: The only times I see a call to `setValue()` happen without its completion handler being called is when there's no network connection (in which case it would be the expected behavior). I'm not sure what's happening for you and it's hard to debug remotely. You could try [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)), so you can see what Firebase sends/receives over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

In the `updateCertificandoKey()` method, instead of `DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(url);`,

try `DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child(url);`.

Comment: i have modified it, but still is ignoring the listener

Comment: But a good point though: can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value for `remoteConfig.getRamaCertificados()`? If so, please do so and update your question to reflect. Reducing the number of variables/dependencies is a key to creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (study the link please, while long it is incredibly useful in getting help).

Comment: apparently it was solved, but it worked 3 times and not works more. A question: the listener is self removed? or it needs removed manually? (after three successful tests i have the same issue, but i think that the IAM rules are not part of the problem).

Comment: What did you do that solved it? And why is it only working thrice without any other changes? Perhaps it's your Android project's fault? Try cleaning and rebuilding your project, maybe?

Comment: some weird stuff are happening with the database, for example: i have tried to insert data in the database 10 times, but the data is not showing in the database console, after of this, i have entered to database rules to check something, but when i go back to database option, the data inserted are visible now, i clean de data of database and i do a new attemp of data insertion and nothing happens, the data are not inserted.

Comment: i have made some changes based on another questions here, these changes are:

(1) i have updated firebase dependencies on gradle from 9.2.0 to 9.6.1
(2) i have generated again and updated in my project the google-services.json, for some reason, is longest than the previous file
(3) i used a data transfer object to contain the data to be updated at database, and i used the setValue(object) method

currently it works fine, i hope it keep ok. Thaks!!

Comment: Great! I hope it stays fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution, the difference is the listener included like argument in the setValue() method. In debug mode, the condition inside of onComplete(...) is not executed (weird), but when de app is running, it does and shows the log message in android monitor. The code is:

```
    String key = String.valueOf(timestamp);
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String certifDate = DataFormatter.simpleDateFromMillis(timestamp);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
    DatabaseReference dataRef = databaseReference.child(remoteConfig.getRamaCertificados()).
            child(key).child(uid);
    dataRef.setValue(certifDate, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            int x = 0;
            if (databaseError != null) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
            } else {
                Log.e("FLAG", "Data saved successfully.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: apparently it was solved, but it worked 3 times and not works more. A question: the listener is self removed? or it needs removed manually? (after three successful tests i have the same issue, but i think that the IAM rules are not part of the problem).

Comment: In the log i see: 47.850 19257-20541/com.appcomfatolima I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with hardcored values:

```
private void updateCertificadoKey(final long timestamp){
    String key = String.valueOf(timestamp);
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String certifDate = DataFormatter.simpleDateFromMillis(timestamp);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
    DatabaseReference dataRef = databaseReference.child("certificados").
            child("key_example").child("uid_example");

    Log.e("FLAG", "******** dataRef: " + dataRef.toString());
    Log.e("FLAG", "******** BEFORE SETVALUE, certifDate: " + certifDate);

    dataRef.setValue(certifDate, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            String x = null;
                if (databaseError != null) {
                x = "1";
                Log.e("ERROR", "Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
            } else {
                x = "2";
                Log.e("FLAG", "Data saved successfully.");
            }
            Log.e("********* x=", x);
        }
    });

    Log.e("FLAG", "AFTER SETVALUE");

}
```

And this is the log with setLogLevel (verbose, no filters), i have put flags:

```
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-3976/? I/CastMediaRouteProvider: in onDiscoveryRequestChanged: request=null
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-10676/? I/DiscoveryManager: Filter criteria(null) scannerFlags(0)
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-10676/? I/Publisher: onUpdateFilterCriteria null
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-10676/? E/Publisher: ProcessDatabaseInternal start
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-10676/? W/MdnsClient_Cast: Multicast lock held. Releasing. Subtypes:"D2CA5178"
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-6940/? I/System.out: [CDS]close[5353]
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-10676/? W/MdnsClient: unicast receiver thread is already dead.
07-02 00:11:38.370 3976-10676/? I/DeviceScanner: [MDNS] notifyDevicesOffline: []
07-02 00:11:38.380 3976-10676/? E/Publisher: ProcessDatabaseInternal start
07-02 00:11:38.380 5087-5087/? A/MessageQueue: IdleHandler threw exception
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at X.1lF.b(:318521)
                                                   at X.0TN.queueIdle(:75051)
                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:207)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 00:11:38.390 2758-2774/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
07-02 00:11:38.390 2758-3194/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
07-02 00:11:38.400 2758-3194/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
07-02 00:11:38.430 3139-3873/? W/UdcContextManagerHelper: Empty context buffer. Thus might mean that the context is not synced down.
07-02 00:11:38.430 3139-3873/? W/GetDeviceDataUploadOptInStatusOp: Empty context model while retrieving upload opt-in status!
07-02 00:11:38.450 3139-3873/? W/UdcContextManagerHelper: Empty context buffer. Thus might mean that the context is not synced down.
07-02 00:11:38.450 3139-3873/? W/GetDeviceDataUploadOptInStatusOp: Empty context model while retrieving upload opt-in status!
07-02 00:11:38.480 2758-2774/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
07-02 00:11:38.490 2758-2769/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
07-02 00:11:42.180 2758-2774/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
07-02 00:11:43.850 19257-19257/com.appcomfatolima I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:3 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
07-02 00:11:43.850 19257-19257/com.appcomfatolima I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
07-02 00:11:44.040 2758-2772/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.appcomfatolima/.familia.FamiliaLauncherActivity: +311ms
07-02 00:11:44.220 19257-19297/com.appcomfatolima W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
07-02 00:11:44.470 19257-20236/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]connect[appcomfatolima.firebaseio.com/104.197.250.13:443]
07-02 00:11:44.610 19257-20236/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]port[59071]
07-02 00:11:45.100 19257-20236/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]close[59071]
07-02 00:11:45.100 19257-20236/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:59071]
07-02 00:11:45.260 19257-20322/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]connect[s-usc1c-nss-121.firebaseio.com/104.154.130.226:443]
07-02 00:11:45.400 19257-20322/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]port[57257]
07-02 00:11:46.290 19257-20322/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]close[57257]
07-02 00:11:46.290 19257-20322/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:57257]
07-02 00:11:47.080 19257-19297/com.appcomfatolima W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
07-02 00:11:47.080 19257-19297/com.appcomfatolima W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
07-02 00:11:47.100 3976-10676/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB3RytXFI5qcnIsLFFOo_fVJ4SkUeuzo-Y, method: 1 ]
07-02 00:11:47.120 3976-10676/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
07-02 00:11:47.130 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
07-02 00:11:47.130 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
07-02 00:11:47.130 19257-20483/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]connect[s-usc1c-nss-121.firebaseio.com/104.154.130.226:443]
07-02 00:11:47.270 19257-19257/com.appcomfatolima E/FLAG: ******** dataRef: https://appcomfatolima.firebaseio.com/certificados/key_example/uid_example
07-02 00:11:47.270 19257-19257/com.appcomfatolima E/FLAG: ******** BEFORE SETVALUE, certifDate: 2017-07-02
07-02 00:11:47.280 19257-19257/com.appcomfatolima E/FLAG: AFTER SETVALUE
07-02 00:11:47.280 19257-20483/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]port[56238]
07-02 00:11:47.850 19257-20541/com.appcomfatolima I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
07-02 00:11:48.070 19257-20483/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]close[56238]
07-02 00:11:48.070 19257-20483/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:56238]
07-02 00:11:48.530 3976-23086/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB3RytXFI5qcnIsLFFOo_fVJ4SkUeuzo-Y, method: 1 ]
07-02 00:11:48.530 3976-23086/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
07-02 00:11:48.540 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
07-02 00:11:48.540 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
07-02 00:11:48.540 19257-20594/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]connect[s-usc1c-nss-121.firebaseio.com/104.154.130.226:443]
07-02 00:11:48.680 19257-20594/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]port[36251]
07-02 00:11:48.860 15842-15941/? I/Finsky: [909] com.google.android.finsky.g.d.a(24): Completed 0 account content syncs with 0 successful.
07-02 00:11:48.860 15842-15842/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.services.e.a(5): Installation state replication succeeded.
07-02 00:11:49.440 19257-20594/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]close[36251]
07-02 00:11:49.440 19257-20594/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36251]
07-02 00:11:50.400 3976-10676/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB3RytXFI5qcnIsLFFOo_fVJ4SkUeuzo-Y, method: 1 ]
07-02 00:11:50.400 3976-10676/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
07-02 00:11:50.410 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
07-02 00:11:50.410 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
07-02 00:11:50.410 19257-20745/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]connect[s-usc1c-nss-121.firebaseio.com/104.154.130.226:443]
07-02 00:11:50.500 2917-2917/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: HEART-BEAT-ACK: 496
07-02 00:11:50.560 19257-20745/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]port[42825]
07-02 00:11:51.360 19257-20745/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]close[42825]
07-02 00:11:51.360 19257-20745/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:42825]
07-02 00:11:52.680 3976-23086/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB3RytXFI5qcnIsLFFOo_fVJ4SkUeuzo-Y, method: 1 ]
07-02 00:11:52.690 3976-23086/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
07-02 00:11:52.700 19257-20923/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]connect[s-usc1c-nss-121.firebaseio.com/104.154.130.226:443]
07-02 00:11:52.700 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
07-02 00:11:52.700 3976-23086/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
07-02 00:11:52.840 19257-20923/com.appcomfatolima I/System.out: [CDS]port[37260]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your `firebase.database` version to the newest version.
The same happened to me.